# Row Level Security not working as expected

Tags: azure-sql-database, row-level-security

I have a requirement to restrict access to rows belonging to `RegionID` 1. Not sure how I create predicate function to satisfy this condition in predicate function? I have even tried hard-coding 0 & 1 as return statements but it still returns everything, no filtering whatsoever.

What could I be doing wrong ?

The one below would not even compile. I tried Case statement as well it compiles but returns everything without filtering.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION RLS.fn_RegionLimit(@RegionID int)
RETURNS table
with schemabinding
AS
   IF @RegionID=1
      RETURN 1
   ELSE
      RETURN 2

create security policy rls.PatientsSecurityPolicy
ADD Filter PREDICATE RLS.fn_RegionLimit(RegionID) on dbo.TestOrder
WITH (STATE=ON)

Select * from dbo.TestOrder
```

Comment: Just wanted to highlight that it is must to use Select statement, Return with literal does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this for certain users only?  Do you not want to apply it certain users or roles only?  This sounds a bit dangerous.

The thing to bear in mind is that the security function is a table-valued function so you have to code it in that way.  There are a few more examples [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2015/04/23/row-level-security-performance-and-common-patterns/).

I have worked up an example based on this security function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_securitypredicate( @regionId INT )
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN

    SELECT 1 AS fn_securitypredicate_result
    WHERE @regionId = 1
       OR IS_SRVROLEMEMBER( N'sysadmin' ) = 1;

GO
```

This applies the restriction to EVERYONE except sysadmins, which I've added as a safety condition.  I have posted the complete script as a gist which you can view [here](https://gist.github.com/wBobuk/4f73d499b98c28fb283436107757f134).